# 2D Tile-Based Game Engine - Layer Management in XNA with C#

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

I'm going to build an advanced 2D Up-Down RPG.

It'll be a C# + XNA version of my existing 2D Flash RPG Engine ( Adobe Air ).

Well, in Flash Pro i've simply used different MovieClips for the different Layers but how could i realize that in C# using XNA ?

I want to be able to use the output ( map-data-file ) from the Flash Map Editor I've made.

The Output file looks like this:

```
<layer1>
0.0.0.A.A.A.A.B.B.A.A.0.0.0
0.0.0.A.A.A.A.B.B.B.A.A.0.0
0.0.A.A.A.B.B.B.B.B.B.A.0.0
0.A.A.A.A.B.B.B.B.B.B.A.A.0
0.A.A.A.A.B.B.B.B.B.B.A.A.0
0.A.A.A.A.A.B.B.B.B.B:B.A.0
0.0.A.A.A.A.B.B.B.B.A.A.A.0
0.0.A.A.A.A.A.B.B.A.A.A.0.0
0.0.0.A.A.A.A.B.B.A.A.0.0.0

<layer2>
. . . . . 
. . .
.
.

<layer3>
.
.
.
```

an so on...

where:

```
0 = Blank;
A = Gras;
B = Water;
```

so i want to simply loop through these lines, save in arrays and add the coresponding sprites to the specific layer, maybe like this:

```
Layers[2].Add( tile, x, y );
```

how can i realize that ? and also, how can I manage the z-sorting, cuz further i want to be able to walk under bridges, or drive through tunnels.

( like in this image, there could be a ship driving unter the bridge )

[image]

or even some stairs to get to the next stage ( switch layer )

do you guys have any idea or even a refference for me ?

thx for all your answers !

EDIT:

the layer hirachy shoult look like this :

```
map{
    Layer[0] { // "bg"
        xyArray{ .... }
    }
    Layer[1] { // "static" - bottom part / stairs of the bridge
        xyArray{ .... }
    }
    Layer[2] { // "items"
        xyArray{ .... }
    }
    Layer[3] { // "player"
        xyArray{ .... }
    }
    Layer[4] { // "static2" - top part of bridge
        xyArray{ .... }
    }
}

// if the player is ON a tile that hat a Stair funktion, the "player" layer will be
// moved on top of the "static2" layer, so 'Layer[3].Z = 4;' and 'Layer[4].Z = 3;'
// like i showed in the Switch funktion up there
```

Comment: I've done something like that where I set the Z of a sprite to the Y coordinate of its bottom and added some offset to account for layers. But it was a somewhat simpler game than this. Would it be enough for for this game?

Comment: i dont really understand that. did you set the z axis of each sprite for its own ?
i want to be able to switch layers later on like 'Switch(Layer[2], Layer[4] ), so i want to simply set 'Layer[2].Z = 4' and 'Layer[4].Z = 2' instead of seting the Z of each sprite in that layer.

Comment: @Ace: there isn't a layer concept in XNA. You need eventually to implement this kind of logic.

Comment: I didn't pre-set the Z of the sprites, because it changes. It changes every time they take a step in the Y axis. It would also change if the sprite walks to an other layer, or if layers were switched (though in my game, neither of these things happens). I calculate the Z just before drawing the sprite, based on current Y and Layer.

Comment: @Heisenbug I know there is no intigrated way, thats why i've asked the question "How to realize that"

Comment: @harold wha did u change the Z of a Sprite based on the Y coordinate ? i want a simple hirachy ( see my edit ) where i just set the .Z parameter of each layer. my cuestion is simple, what is the way to define the Z in 2D ? I've heared about using diferent SpriteBatches for each layer ? and draw them in they hirachy ?
can i play with some attributes of the 2D camera ? XNA is new to me , i dont know all the classes...

Comment: That is to properly order "tall" sprites, that cover not just the tile they are on but the one above too. If you don't have anything like that, it doesn't matter.

Comment: ahh ok, well i'm just searching for a propper way to Tell the SpriteBatch that THIS TILE IS Z = 3 and THAT TILE IS Z = 6, or whatever i've defined for the Z...

SHOULD I JUST DRAW THEM IN THE CORRECT ORDER ? OR CAN I TELL THE RENDERER WHICH ONE IS ON THE TOP / BOTTOM / MIDDLE ????

Comment: SpriteBatch sucks. It seems useful at first, but it tends to mess things up later. Drawing them in order works, though.

Comment: so , if spriteBatch sucks, what else could i use to draw that stuff ?

Comment: `device.DrawUserPrimitives` or similar. You might get away with using SpriteBatch, but then again, maybe not.

Comment: what is the difference ?

Comment: The difference is that it doesn't try to do anything for you. So it's a little harder to use, but SpriteBatch has a habit of automatically doing the *wrong* thing for you.

Comment: hmm, okay. so i'll give it a try. if it's too confusing I'll keep doin it with spriteBatch where i render in correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SpriteBatch.Draw` method has overloads that let you specify Layer

Specifically, the bottom two entries on the table [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx)

The layer is a float between 0 and 1. You'll also need to specify a `SpriteSortMode` in your `SpriteBatch.Begin()`. Below is an example from a board game I wrote that tints the player tokens and moves the active player to the very front of the stack for when multiple players occupy the same square:

```
if (i == currentPlayer)
{
     SpriteColor = Color.White;
     spriteDepth = 0f; // Front
}
else
{
     SpriteColor = Color.Gray;
     spriteDepth = 0.1f; // Back
}
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
spriteBatch.Draw(players[i].Sprite, SquareCentre, null, SpriteColor, 0f, SpriteCentre,0.5f, SpriteEffects.None, spriteDepth);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give it a try and see if it works with my vurrent layer management setup. thx